# Escape quotes for a command passed to cmd with /c option

Tags: cmd

How should I pass a command to `cmd /c` when the full path of the command may have spaces in its path and when its arguments may also have spaces?

For example, "print arg.py" (without quotes) is a command which happens to have a space in its basename for demonstration purpose, as a substitute for cases of full paths having spaces, and it prints arguments it takes in a nice form.

```
c:\t>"print arg.py" "a b" "c d"
(a b)
(c d)
end
```

Here are some failed attempts at passing that command to `cmd /c`:

```
c:\t>cmd /c "print arg.py" "a b" "c d"
Unable to initialize device PRN

c:\t>cmd /c """print arg.py"" ""a b"" ""c d"""
Unable to initialize device PRN

c:\t>cmd /c "\"print arg.py\" \"a b\" \"c d\""
'\"print arg.py\"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
cmd /c ""print arg.py" "a b" "c d""
```

That should give you the result you want.